# Why does cat < /dev/ttyS0 send output to ttyS0?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, serial-port, cat

When I use `cat < /dev/ttyS0` and data is received, it doesn't display on the terminal that I typed the command into but instead gets sent back to to ttyS0 where it came from. How can I make it not do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not sent back but echoed, try

```
stty -echo </dev/ttyS0
cat </dev/ttyS0
```

and echo should be suppressed.